# Finding the derivative of a messy function

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I need to find the derivative of this function. I think I managed to do this, but the simplification is messy. Is there a good way to keep things organized while I go through all of the needed differentiation rules? It was hard to stay focused in even writing this in latex.

$y = \frac{\sqrt[3]{2x}\sqrt{x+5}}{(4x-1)^9}$

> numerator(u)/denominator(v)
>   $u = \sqrt[3]{2x}\sqrt{x+5}$
>   $v = (4x-1)^9$
>
> derivative of numerator(u')/denominator(v')
>   $u' =\frac{(2x)^{\frac{1}{3}}(x+5)^{-\frac{1}{2}}}{2} + \frac{(x+5)^{\frac{1}{2}}(2x)^{-\frac{2}{3}}}{3}$  product rule, chain rule
>   $v' = 36(4x-1)^8$  chain rule

quotient rule $\frac{vu' - uv'}{v^2}$

$= \frac{\bigg(\frac{(2x)^{\frac{1}{3}}(x+5)^{-\frac{1}{2}}}{2} + \frac{(x+5)^{\frac{1}{2}}(2x)^{-\frac{2}{3}}}{3} \bigg) - 36\sqrt[3]{2x}\sqrt{x+5}\ (4x-1)^8}{(4x-1)^9}$

$= \frac{\bigg(\frac{\sqrt[3]{2x}}{2\sqrt{x+5}} + \frac{\sqrt{x+5}}{6\sqrt[3]{2x}} \bigg) - 36\sqrt[3]{2x}\sqrt{x+5}\ (4x-1)^8}{(4x-1)^9}$

Suffice to say this is a mess, does a less-tedious way exist to find the derivative?

Comment: I haven't checked your work, but confirm your method. There is no easier way.

Comment: Very simple with computer algebra:  $-\frac{196 x^2+1045 x+10}{3\ 2^{2/3} (1-4 x)^{10} x^{2/3} \sqrt{x+5}}$

Answer (score 4):

The [classical trick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_differentiation) is to consider
\begin{align}
\ln y = \frac{1}{3}\ln(2x)+\frac{1}{2}\ln(x+5)-9\ln(4x-1)
\end{align}
then differentiate to get
\begin{align}
\frac{y'}{y} =&\ \frac{1}{3x}+\frac{1}{2(x+5)}-\frac{36}{4x-1}\\
=&\ -\frac{196x^2+1045x+10}{6x(x+5)(4x-1)}.
\end{align}
Hence it follows
\begin{align}
y' =&\ -y\frac{196x^2+1045x+10}{6x(x+5)(4x-1)} = - \frac{\sqrt[3]{2x}\sqrt{x+5}}{(4x-1)^9}\frac{196x^2+1045x+10}{6x(x+5)(4x-1)} \\
=&\ - \frac{196x^2+1045x+10}{3\cdot 2^{2/3} x^{2/3}\sqrt{x+5}(4x-1)^{10}}
\end{align}

**Remark**: In the grand scheme of things, it doesn't save much time in terms of getting a simplified expression. However, it does have some organizational benefits.

**Remark $2$**: As mentioned by egreg, we can also write
\begin{align}
\ln |y| = \ln\left|\frac{\sqrt[3]{2x}\sqrt{x+5}}{(4x-1)^9}\right| = \frac{1}{3}\ln|2x|+\frac{1}{2}\ln|x+5|-9\ln|4x-1|
\end{align}
and use the fact that 
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx}\ln|f(x)| = \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}.
\end{align}

Comment: It is worth remarking that this is a formal method and it doesn't matter if the expressions we take the logarithm of are negative for some value of $x$.